# How to build dataframe of variable search strings for web scraping

Tags: r, for-loop, pagination, web-scraping, paste

I'm trying to build a dataframe that will help me paginate some simple web scraping. What is the best way to build a dataframe where each row uses the same base URL string but varies a few specific characters, which can be specified according to the pagination one needs.

Let's say you have a set of search results where there is a total of 4485 results, 10 per page, spread out over 449 pages. All I want for the moment is to make a dataframe with one variable where each row is a character string of the URL with a variable, sequenced page number along the lines of:

```
**Var1**
http://begin.com/start=0/index.html
http://begin.com/start=10/index.html
http://begin.com/start=20/index.html
http://begin.com/start=30/index.html
```

...
http://begin.com/start=4480/index.html

Here's my original strategy but this fails (and yea it's inefficient and newbish).

```
startstring<-"http://begin.com/start="
variableterm<-seq(from=0, to=4485, by=10)
endstring<-"/index.html"

df <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow=449, ncol=1))
for (x in 1:length(variableterm)){ 
for(i in variableterm){
df[x,]<-c(paste(startstring,i,endstring, sep=""))
}
}
```

But every single row is equal to http://begin.com/start=4480/index.html. How can I change this so that each row gives the same URL but with a different number increasing like in the desired dataframe above?

I would very much appreciate how to achieve this with my strategy (just to learn) but of course better approaches are welcome also. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you would need this to be in a data frame. Here is one way to create a vector of page urls.

```
sprintf("http://begin.com/start=%s/index.html", seq(0, 4490, 10))
```

Comment: Hahaha the time wasted by ignorance, yes, of course, brilliant.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The reason you have each row returning the same value (the last value) is that you have two loops where you only require a single. The first loop is looping through the rows of the data frame and the second loop is looping through the entire set of URLs and leaving the last one as the value of the data frame's row before the first loop moves to the next row.

This should work as you would expect:

```
for(i in 1:length(variableterm)){
    df[i,]<-paste(startstring,variableterm[i],endstring, sep="")
}
```